# Can I get the md5_file() files in tmp folder using PHP?

Tags: php, md5

**Case** : I'm trying to check whenever the upload files is duplicate.

Q : Can I get the `md5_file();` output from the temporary files..? There is will be same value of the `md5_file();` from its real file ?

This is my unworking code : `md5_file(sys_get_temp_dir().$file->getTempName());`

This is the output :

> md5_file(C:\Windows\TEMPC:\Windows\Temp\phpDC34.tmp)

My friends tell it possible, but how can I do that..? I think that impossible to get hash file from tmp files..

Comment: are you saying the above code does not work?

Comment: it should work. but your path/filename is duplicated.

Comment: @Dagon, no I mean that is possible to proccessing file in the tmp (temporary files), because i want to get the md5_file() from it.

Comment: it works.. sry i dont realize the path is invalid, after i use the tmp_path it should be work

Comment: sry, thank for your time.

Comment: @James yes, sry i dont realize it duplicated.